# Could Quantum Entanglement be related with gravitational interactions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, quantum-entanglement

Particles are entangled when they share the same state and their properties become correlated. Interaction with one of them, by say measurement, is experienced instantly by the other.

If we measure a property that determines the energy(mass) of one of the particles in the entangled system, this will determine instantly the energies(masses) of all the rest of the particles of the system. Then gravity must be affected by the quantum state of the particles, because energy interacts with (i.e., it is a source of) gravity.

Now, all the particles came into existence instantly (Big Bang), and we know only 4% of the Universe, which leaves us a lot of margin for the existence of entangled particles.

Considering that every particle in the Universe interacts with all the mass of the rest of the Universe. Could it be the case that there is some relation.

Comment: All I know is that this is Experimentally identified phenomenon, with descriptive character, i.e. no real explanation why does it happen, only that it happens.

Comment: There is no "spooky action at a distance", so nothing to explain. Also, gravitational interaction is mediated at the speed of light...

Comment: No interaction - this would have to travel at the speed of light. It's a nonlocal effect of correlations, which just happens to exist because of the structure of qantum mechanics. See the many other questions about entanglement.

Comment: Massless objects are required to travel at $c$.

Answer (score 2):

This an emerging line of work. See a complete workshop on that http://benasque.org/2015gil/

The idea is that clocks based on entangled ion traps are approaching precisions of one part in 10^20. For instance Wineland has been able to detect general relativity effects in a lab by just raising one of his clocks just 3cm.

The question remains if variation of entanglement may detect gravitational effects.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that many interactions are very short-range, while gravity tends to act over long distances. However, gravity is not unique in this--electromagnetic forces also die off with $r^{-2}$. It's true that in practice, the intercession of opposing charges tends to screen this interaction, so you often don't see "bare" Coulomb interactions like that.

However, this is not the "spooky" part of the "distance" in "spooky action at a distance" (a phrase which should not be taken very seriously). After all, if the interaction between atoms in our laboratories was simply long range this would not be so astounding--after all, when light reaches us from stars, this is an electromagnetic interaction that occurs at a truly incredibly distance. The "spooky" part is the sense in which this interaction appears (naively) to be instantaneous. If you and I share an entangled state, once I measure my half of it your measurement is no longer random, but has to be anti-correlated with mine. So if I measured $+1$, it is now definitive that you will measure $-1$. This is pretty weird. But note that when you make the measurement, you can't tell whether you were guaranteed to get $-1$ or whether it was 50/50 like usual. So we can't do anything until we call each other later (over classical channels) and share our results, and then we can use the shared information we have to e.g. do encryption. As a result it is still impossible to use this strange feature of quantum mechanics to construct any sort of faster-than-light influence.

Comment: I get your point, that, measuring one of the entangled particles can not give us information about the other. However, are quantum objects required to communicate through classical channels.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: Entangled objects don't *communicate* in the sense of sending informtion to each other. An entangled system is a *single* object.